Number formatting on new rows after refresh? (Excel power query 2021)
Our office just updated to 2021 after previously being on 2016. I am experiencing a new issue that I haven't before.
When I refresh a sheet, new rows of data are not inherently getting the formatting that was applied to the table/sheet. Columns that have their data justified to center would be left-justified, and such.
The number formatting is the worst part. The query that is outputting to this table on refresh is outputting date data (example 7/11/2010  8:35:18 AM), and existing rows are displayed without the seconds, which is fine, but new rows are displaying as a number (example 40370.3578472222) and using the 'General' number format.
So every time I refresh the sheet I have to select the columns and reapply the date format I want and then reapply the center justification. I didn't have to do this in the 2016 Excel and I'm not sure what's changed.
Any ideas?
I've tried using these settings:External Data Properties settings
The 'preserve cell formatting' and 'insert entire rows' but it doesn't seem to help.
Before when I've had weird quirky issues in excel 2016, it turns out I was missing some patches that our IT had blocked from installation. I think I have the latest version of 2021 though (Build 14332.20721)
